# Import State(developed by javascript) from Vue-Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

My project was developed by Vue js and it has store developed by javascript, and I integrated new component which is developed by vue-typescript and all scripts in this components are developed by typescript.

To import state variable, I tried two ways

use `Vuex`

```
import { mapGetters, mapState, mapActions, mapMutations, createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'

@Component({
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'allowedUrls'
    ])
  }
})
```

this case `this.allowedUrls` is not defined error

Use `Vuex-Class`

```
import { State } from 'vuex-class'
@State allowedUrls: string[]
```

this case, `this.allowedUrls` is always undefined

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where are you evaluating `this.allowedUrls`? If in the `constructor`, `allowedUrls` would not have been initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what is wrong with your code but I do the same thing in a slightly different way and it works:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import RootState from '@/store/rootState';

@Component({
  computed: mapState({
    userFullName: (state: RootState) => state.user.fullName,
    userEmail: (state: RootState) => state.user.email
  })
})
```

`RooState` is my class for the vuex state. I'm using vue 2.5.17 and vuex 3.0.1.